# Saving a user preference/selection of tkinter app

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have a set up screen that a user selects options in. I would like to know how to save those selections, so that every time the program starts up, the user selection stays the same. Would making a database that saves that info work, or is there an easier method? Is making a file to read and write from practical for a program?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: just open file, write to it, then when needed read that written data from it

Comment: Ok, thanks. Answer the question so that I can accept it.